# Extension_attribute value save in DB in magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, quote, extension-attributes

I am using Magento 2.3.4, and i created custom attibute in quote_item 'up_flag'. and throgh rest api i am passing the value of "up_flag":

Post request Body for V1/carts/mine/items:

```
{"cartItem": {"sku": "xxxx", "qty": "1", "quote_id": 28981,"up_flag": "1"}}
```

and i am getting the error "Message: Property "UpFlag" does not have accessor method"

or if i try through Extension attribute method like:

```
{"cartItem": {"sku": "xxxx", "qty": "1", "quote_id": 28975,
"extension_attributes": {    
  
  "up_flag": "1"
}

 }}
```

And Plugins Code:

```
public function afterGet(
    CartRepositoryInterface $subject,
    CartInterface $resultEntity
) {
    foreach ($resultEntity->getItems() as $item) {
        $extensionAttributes = $item->getExtensionAttributes();

        if (!$extensionAttributes) {
            $extensionAttributes = $this->totalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory->create();
        }
        
        $getupflag = $extensionAttributes->getUpFlag();
        $extensionAttributes->setUpFlag($getupflag);
        $item->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
    }
    
    return $resultEntity;
}
```

Response in Postman:

```
NULL
NULL
string(1) "1"
NULL
string(1) "1"
{
"item_id": 5222,
"sku": "PGKFMT1",
"qty": 9,
"name": "XXXXX",
"price": 237.29,
"product_type": "simple",
"quote_id": "28981",
"extension_attributes": {
    "discounts": [
        {
            "discount_data": {
                "amount": 126,
                "base_amount": 126,
                "original_amount": 135,
                "base_original_amount": 135
            },
            "rule_label": "5% discount for prepaid",
            "rule_id": 20
        },
        {
            "discount_data": {
                "amount": 239.4,
                "base_amount": 239.4,
                "original_amount": 257.4,
                "base_original_amount": 257.4
            },
            "rule_label": "discount",
            "rule_id": 6
        }
    ],
    "image_url": "http://localhost/default/pub/static/version1604919926/webapi_rest/_view/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/.jpg"
}
  }
```

Now i always getting first the value fo $getupflag = Null and its not showing in response. even  how i can save "up_flag" value in DB?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create extension attribute like it is explained [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html) . And then, when you have extension attribute, you can send it to API and update it. Remember that extension attribute and some custom attribute is different. Not really sure which one you created, since you say you created custom attribute, but also trying extension attribute update. Anyway, I suggest you to create extension attribute and use it. It is suggested way by Magento2. Also with example it is kind of easy way to implement.

Comment: Hi @Kestutisk, i tried with Extension attribute only, please check my update question.

Comment: You also need to create afterSave and afterGetList plugins for extension attributes. afterSave should save to database, that is what it for.

Comment: after create this plugin, product is not added in cart for guest customer?

Comment: Use xdebug and see what happens. Could be it brakes on some line

Comment: If you have any sample code, can you please share.  i tried with add another two method also, but showing always some issue.